# Formatting DateTime in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to Format my DateTime 2005-08-01T12:00:00 in XSL 1.0. I tried using substring functions but 'T' is still coming.
I want my output to come like this -

```
<YEAR>2005</YEAR>
<MONTH>08</MONTH>
<DAY>01</DAY>
<HOUR>12<HOUR/>
<MINUTE>00<MINUTE/>
<SECOND>00<SECOND/>
```

How to write snippet of this and remove 'T' from the incoming value?

Comment: What does your xslt look like?

Comment: I think you are very fortunate to get an answer to this question. Personally, I never answer a question unless I can see your mistakes: I don't want to write code for people, I want to show them where they have gone wrong so that they learn something from the exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **substring** function for this. Remember, that that the indexing of each character in the string starts at 1 not 0. So, to get the year you would do this (assuming you are currently positioned on a date element)

```
<YEAR><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4) " /></YEAR>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="date">
      <date>
         <YEAR><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4) " /></YEAR>
         <MONTH><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 6, 2) " /></MONTH>
         <DAY><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 9, 2) " /></DAY>
         <HOUR><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 12, 2) " /></HOUR>
         <MINUTE><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 15, 2) " /></MINUTE>
         <SECOND><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 18, 2) " /></SECOND>
      </date>
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<dates>
   <date>2005-08-01T12:00:00</date>
</dates>
```

THe following is output

```
<dates>
   <date>
      <YEAR>2005</YEAR>
      <MONTH>08</MONTH>
      <DAY>01</DAY>
      <HOUR>12</HOUR>
      <MINUTE>00</MINUTE>
      <SECOND>00</SECOND>
   </date>
</dates>
```

Obviously you would have to be sure the dates always came in with the same format for this to work.

Comment: I am glad to be of help. Do note you should 'accept' answers if they work for you, so that others who may look up your questions in the future know what the correct answer is.