# Format the Date in YYYY-MM-DD format in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to transform the XML data for the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Here is the piece of code I wrote

```
<xsl:variable name="Formatted_Date" select="format-date(wd:continuous_service_date,'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Formatted_Date,1,10)"/>`
```

But still its output is `MM/DD/YYYY`.
How do I do this in XSLT?

Comment: What's the value of `wd:continuous_service_date` (and maybe the rest of your relevant code)?

Comment: The value of wd:continuous_service_date is 10/14/2005

Comment: What XSLT version can you use? 1.0 or 2.0 and above? If you can use XSLT-2.0 or above, you can [look here at w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date).

Comment: Its XSLT 1.o Version

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use the `format-date(...)` function for this, because it is an XSLT-2.0 function. There are some approaches of handling this in XSLT-1.0, but each of those is specific in a way.

For example, there are

- ["Formatting DateTime in xslt 1.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10275464/1305969)
- ["Convert date from DD-MMM-YYYY to YYYYMMDD format in xslt 1.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16484193/1305969)

and some others.

---

For your specific case, the following XSLT snippet does what you need:

```
<xsl:variable name="oldDateFormat" select="wd:continuous_service_date" />       
<xsl:variable name="year"  select="substring-after(substring-after($oldDateFormat,'/'),'/')" />
<xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($oldDateFormat,'/')" />
<xsl:variable name="day"   select="substring-before(substring-after($oldDateFormat,'/'),'/')" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat($year,'-',$month,'-',$day)"/>
```

Its output is

```
2005-10-14
```